# Add Deployer deploy.php recipe to .gitignore?

Tags: php, deployment, php-deployer

Should the [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) recipe (config) file **deploy.php** be added to .gitignore?

I could not find any information on this. What is best practice?

Answer (score 1):

If you want others to be able to perform deployment, you should share this file with your team.

I do not see any danger if you avoid use strings with passwords or tokens (like gitlab access token). That's why you should use ssh key instead.

Comment: I think this better serve as a comment instead of an answer. Or maybe you can enrich the answer to make it better.

Comment: You could even make ssh keys and share those. You can define that too in the recipe. Maybe that goes too far. But it is posible.